# Cannot find JSP file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, web

Im trying to connect my JSP file to my spring boot but it is giving me a Whitelabel error saying : Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jul 21 21:05:45 BST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
JSP file [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] not found

My Application properties look like this :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
logging.level.org.springframework.web = DEBUG
```

And here is a screenshot of my code editior and file order:

[image: Controller]

If it helps when I hover over return "login" it says cannot resolve MVC view "login"

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.javaFirstSpringBoot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-first-web-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>spring-boot-first-web-application</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any help as to why would be great or what I should do next,

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try replace propeties on `spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/pages/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp`? Do you have declare WAR or JAR app in pom.xml?

Comment: I have a JAR declared and I have my properties declared correctly

Comment: Try to change jar to war in pom.xml and reload maven.

Comment: Hi this comes up with the same error, I dont know what is going wrong

Comment: Did you declare tomcat-embed-jasper as a dependency in pom.xml?

Comment: Yes, I have, should I add my dependencies to the post?

Comment: JSP only works with WAR packaging, which also means you actually need to create the WAR and run that. Running the `main` won't work with JSP as that is the same as running an executable JAR. I would strongly suggest NOT to use JSP's when using an embedded container. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations.

Comment: @OliverDarby - You seem to have missed some annotation e.g. `@Controller` or maybe some other. I suggest you start with a basic application e.g. https://www.boraji.com/spring-boot-creating-web-application-using-spring-mvc and then try to find the missing code/configuration in your application.

Answer (score 0):

hhmmm,... First, here is a very easy 'step-by-step' instruction.
[german manual](https://o7planning.org/de/11681/anleitung-spring-boot-und-jsp#a14248094) maybe it help.

What I guess is that your application has a name and you forget it in your url? `localhost:8080/appName/login`

Also maybe the @RequestMapping Annotation need also the RequestMapping type GET?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the advice I dont think its the url as Im following a tutorial and they just have localhost:8080/login and it works, I tried it with my application name but it comes up with a different error of just 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by creating the 'webapp' folder shown below.
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp